# Prevent a process from being killed by any user mode means

Tags: terminal, activity-monitor

I use [Freedom](http://freedom.to) to help me stay focused while working. Sometimes I will be so disillusioned with my work, that I will go to such lengths as to try and `kill` the process from the terminal.

I'd like to prevent myself from doing this. **Is it possible to elevate the process so that it can't be killed by any means**, including by using `sudo kill <process ID>` from a terminal?

Comment: Adam, could you clarify your question. It doesn't make sense. 
What process are you trying to kill with the terminal? Freedom?

Comment: I'm trying to prevent Freedom from being killed in the terminal by **any means** including by using the `sudo kill` command from the terminal.

Comment: I've added more clarity to the question, please reopen it. If you still believe it is unclear, please explain why.

Comment: So, the short answer is no. Sending SIGTERM, SIGKILL or any other interruption signals will kill the targeted process. I am still puzzled by your question though :) To me, it is like asking "I have a loaded gun in my hands, I pull the trigger but I would like to know if there is a way to avoid shooting a bullet straight into my head". The logical answer is : "Do not pull the trigger". 
In your context case, it is "Do not sudo kill the process".

Comment: On mac it is actually much easier and you don't need sudo, you can just type `killall Freedom` and it will die.  They should at least name it something confusing like `cfperfsd` (vs cfprefsd) or have it constantly create new binaries that it "hops" to by killing itself and running the new binary, storing the current binary name/path in an encoded format, where `Freedom` just launches that binary, basically making it impossible to find, and have that Freedom binary respawn if you do happen to kill it.  Basically, get creative!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On macOS it is not possible to create processes which can‘t be killed by a user who is able to `sudo`. So the short and simple answer to your question is **NO**.